# System.Linq.Dynamic.Core not behaving similarly to .Net MVC 5 version

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to implement System.Linq.Dynamic.Core in my functions OrderBy. For some reason its giving this error

> 'List' does not contain a definition for 'OrderBy' and the best extension method overload 'DynamicQueryableExtensions.OrderBy(IQueryable, string, params object[])' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable'

```
List<UsersListViewModel> data = (from user in dbContext.Users
 select new UsersListViewModel
 {
     Id = user.Id,
     Name = user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName,
     UserName = user.UserName,
     Email = user.Email,
     PhoneNumber = user.PhoneNumber
 }).ToList();

 if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Input.Order) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(Input.OrderDir)))
{
    var columnName = modelStructure.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Key == Convert.ToInt32(Input.Order));
    data = data.OrderBy(columnName.Value + " " + Input.OrderDir).ToList();
}
```

OrderBy is not allowing my code to compile. In my other ASP.NET MVC 5 application, adding System.Linq.Dynamic would work.

Comment: Have you added  `using System.Linq`?

Comment: Yes I have. In order to use OrderBy, I had to add System.Linq.Dynamic for ASP.NET MVC 5

Comment: I assumed it would be the same for .net core but apparently not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should convert data to  IQueryable:

```
using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core;

    List<UsersListViewModel> data = (from user in dbContext.Users
     select new UsersListViewModel
     {
         Id = user.Id,
         Name = user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName,
         UserName = user.UserName,
         Email = user.Email,
         PhoneNumber = user.PhoneNumber
     }).ToList();

     if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Input.Order) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(Input.OrderDir)))
    {
        var columnName = modelStructure.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Key == Convert.ToInt32(Input.Order));
        data = data.OrderBy(columnName.Value + " " + Input.OrderDir).ToList();
    }

     if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Input.Order) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(Input.OrderDir)))
    {
        var columnName = modelStructure.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Key == Convert.ToInt32(Input.Order));
        data = data.AsQueryable().OrderBy(x=> x.).ToList();
    }
```